# How to understand GET and POST in my Flask Application

Tags: python, flask, web, post, get

I'm creating a TODO List App and I'm trying to understand how POST and GET methods work.

I have two routes in my Flask application. One route is for register, and the other route is for add_task, which dynamically outputs tasks onto the same html page.

What I don't understand is why the register route requires that I specify GET and POST inside the methods parameter for me to access it, because if I don't I get a new page pop up with an error saying "Method is not allowed", yet I only need to specify POST for the add_task parameter for me to access it, and it gives me no issues. I have also made sure that in my form tag I have included the `{{ url_for("xyz" method="post") }}` inside my html templates.

I know by adding GET to the methods parameter in the register route solves my issue, however I have trouble understanding why, and why do I need to specify it, when I don't have to specify GET for the add_task route. This is my first flask project I'm doing on my own without following any tutorials, so I want to make sure I fully understand every line of code.

````
    @app.route("/register", methods=["POST"])
    def register():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form['name']
        email = request.form['email']
        password = request.form['password']
        print(f"Name:{name}\nEmail:{email}\nPassword:{password}")
        return redirect(url_for('register'))
    return render_template('register.html')


    @app.route("/add_task", methods=["POST"])
    def add_task():
    if request.method == "GET":
        print("Get method is being made")
    if request.method == "POST" and request.form['message'] != "":
        add_task = request.form['message']
        with app.app_context():
            new_task = Tasks(title=add_task)
            db.session.add(new_task)
            db.session.commit()
        success = "Task added"
        return redirect(url_for('my_tasks', success=success))  
    else:
        error = "Please enter a task"
    return render_template("home.html", tasks=tasks, error=error) ```
````

### Edit

Full server side code:

```
    from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, redirect, request
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
    from flask_login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_user, logout_user, login_required, current_user
    import datetime as dt
    
    
    app = Flask("__main__")
    app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "secret-key"
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///tasks.db"
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
    date = dt.datetime.now()
    
    #CREATING CLASS OBJECTS
    login_manager = LoginManager()
    db = SQLAlchemy()
    
    #INITIALISING CLASS OBJECTS AND PASSING IN THE FLASK APPLICATION
    #login_manager.init_app(app)
    db.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    
    tasks = []
    year = date.year
    
    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(user_id):
        return User.get(user_id)
    
    class Tasks(db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True) #EVERY TABLE MUST HAVE A PRIMARY KEY COLUMN
        title = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    
    class User(UserMixin,db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
        email = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False, unique=True)
        password = db.Column(db.String(1000), nullable=False)
    
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
    
    
    @app.route("/")
    def home():
        return render_template("home.html")
    
    @app.route("/my_tasks")
    def my_tasks():
        tasks.clear()
        all_tasks = db.session.query(Tasks).all()
        for task in all_tasks:
            tasks.append(task)
        success = request.args.get('success')
        deleted = request.args.get('deleted')
        all_deleted = request.args.get('all_deleted')
        return render_template("mytasks.html", year=year, tasks=tasks, success=success, deleted=deleted, all_deleted=all_deleted)
    
    @app.route("/add_task", methods=["POST"])
    def add_task():
        if request.method == "GET":
            print("Get method is being made")
        if request.method == "POST" and request.form['message'] != "":
            add_task = request.form['message']
            with app.app_context():
                new_task = Tasks(title=add_task)
                db.session.add(new_task)
                db.session.commit()
            success = "Task added"
            return redirect(url_for('my_tasks', success=success))  # Redirect to the My Tasks Page after successful submission
        else:
            error = "Please enter a task"
    
        return render_template("home.html", tasks=tasks, error=error)
    
    @app.route("/delete_task/<int:id>", methods=["GET"])
    def delete_task(id):
        task_id = id
        task_to_delete = Tasks.query.get(task_id)
        db.session.delete(task_to_delete)
        db.session.commit()
        deleted = "Task Deleted"
        return redirect(url_for('my_tasks', deleted=deleted))
    
    @app.route("/delete_all")
    def delete_all():
        all_tasks = db.session.query(Tasks).all()
        for task in all_tasks:
            print(task.id)
            task_id = task.id
            task_to_delete = Tasks.query.get(task_id)
            db.session.delete(task_to_delete)
            db.session.commit()
        all_deleted = "Task list deleted"
        return redirect(url_for("my_tasks",all_deleted=all_deleted))
    
    @app.route("/login", methods=["GET","POST"])
    def login():
        if request.method == "GET":
            print("Get request is being made")
        if request.method == "POST":
            print("Post request is being made")
            email = request.form["email"]
            password = request.form["password"]
            print(f"Email:{email}\nPassword:{password}")
            return redirect(url_for("login"))
        return render_template("login.html")
    
    
    @app.route("/register", methods=["POST"])
    def register():
        if request.method == "GET":
            print("Get request is being made")
        if request.method == 'POST':
            name = request.form['name']
            email = request.form['email']
            password = request.form['password']
            print(f"Name:{name}\nEmail:{email}\nPassword:{password}")
            return redirect(url_for('register'))
        return render_template('register.html')
    
    @app.route("/logout")
    def logout():
        return render_template("home.html")
    
    
    if __name__ == ("__main__"):
        app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256385/discussion-on-question-by-codingowl-need-help-understanding-get-and-post-in-my-f); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.